# Android - applicationWillTerminate equivalent

Tags: android, ios, terminate

Is there a way to tell when my android app will terminate? In iOS there is a method in the AppDelegate

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.

}
```

I need this because I want to do something only when the application will be finished running, and not when it enters the background or a specific activity is ended.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell when my android app will terminate?

No. Your process can go away at any time, for any reason, once it is in the background. You are not notified that your process is about to be terminated.

> I want to do something only when the application will be finished running

There isn't really a concept in Android of "finished running".

Answer (score 0):

this is the closest thing i can think of that might be usefull for you this is just on an Activity level though

```
 @Override 
public void onPause() {        

        if(isFinishing()){
//code to finish() all activitys threads etc.....
}            

    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try onDestroy() method. It gets called when app is terminated

Comment: I ran some tests with this, and it is not reliable.  This seems to fire sometimes, but not always.  Or, at least it doesn't always run long enough to write to a log...  I've been thinking of trying to use this, but just not counting on it.